# What is the correct CVSS “Privileges Required” score for a local privilege escalation where the vulnerable component doesn’t do authorization?

Tags: cvss

A locally installed application, which runs a daemon as root, creates a directory which is world-writable. By changing files in this world-writable directory, it’s possible to cause the daemon to execute arbitrary code as root.

Reviewing the [Privileges Required flowchart](https://www.first.org/cvss/user-guide#Scoring-Rubrics) from the official CVSS user guide doesn’t seem to offer a clear answer to what the correct PR value is in this case.

Is the correct CVSSv3 Privileges Required score for this vulnerability:

1. None, because the attacker doesn’t need to be authorized by the vulnerable component (the service daemon)?
2. Low, because the attacker needs to have access to a user account on the machine in order to write to the world-writable directory?
3. High, because “having an account on the same computer as the victim is a High Privilege”?